# I can't be able to run my React native expo application

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo, cross-platform

I have created a react native expo application using "Expo init" command and chose the blank typescript option.  When I run the application using "expo run:android" I get an error saying "7 errors w: Detected multiple kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions. I will share the image below. I'm using Parrot OS home, expo version 6.3.7, node version 16.17.0. How cn I solve the problem and be able to run the react native expo app.[Screenshot one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HQU2.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeVs7.png)

I have tried changing gradle version but I was unsuccesful

Comment: try 'npm start' instead of "expo run:android"

Comment: I don't want to run it on the expo go app